# How can i track notifications in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a web application where i need to notify the administrators of certain activities on the site. I have implemented a **Message** class which i use to create notifications. These messages are loaded by a Service Provider each time and shared to all the views. My problem now is how to update messages list on a global scope after an administrator acts on the list. For example if admin1 reads a message i want admin2 and admin3 to realize that the message in question has been replied.

Comment: You probably thought of it, but why not use a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem. I actually used a service provider in which i load the messages from the database. The latte is being called for every request that the user sends hence by just refreshing the page each administrator will be able to get the updates on each of the notifications.